# How can the block possibly accelerate towards the right in the image?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Friction on every surface is smooth and the wedge is not restricted to move so wedge can move. Also, the mass of the wedge is $m$, as is the mass of the block. The question is that sir? told that in the ground frame the block will experience acceleration in direction of $b$ and $a$. How can that be possible because I drew a Free Body Diagram of the block and there is no force in direction of $a$? So since there is no force in direction of $a$ then how can block have acceleration $a$?

[image: Image of the class screenshot and FBD I drew]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this block move backwards?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578063/)

Comment: @Philip Thanks for reaching out to help me. The answer below satisfied me and I think was the correct answer to my question. Thanks a lot, your effort is very very much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block slides down the wedge in direction $\vec b$, but the wedge accelerates in direction $\vec a$, so the motion of the block relative to the ground will not be in direction $\vec b$ but will make a smaller angle with the vertical than $\vec b$.

You are right to say that the block must still move to the left relative to the ground as it slides - it cannot move to the right relative to the ground. You can see this by considering the forces on the block or by thinking about the position of the centre of mass of the block and wedge together. The COM cannot move horizontally because there are no external horizontal forces acting on the system. So if the wedge moves to the right then the block must move to the left - and since they have equal masses they are displaced left and right by equal distances at any given time.

Comment: If the acceleration, a, is big enough, or if the angle is small enough, isn't it possible that the block accelerates (moves) to the right instead of to the left?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder If both the block and the wedge move to the right then the COM of the whole system moves to the right. But this is only possible if there is a net horizontal force on the whole system e.g. if there is an external force pushing the wedge to the right.

Comment: But there **is** an acceleration, ain't there?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder The block is accelerating to the left and the wedge is accelerating to the right, but for the total system (block and wedge together) there is no horizontal acceleration because there is no external horizontal force.

Comment: If there is no external force, then what makes the wedge accelerate to the right (as is the block, for accelerations that are not too high)?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder The block pushes on the wedge, so the wedge accelerates to the right. The wedge pushes on the block, so the block accelerates to the left.

Comment: @BioPhysicist So its the block that's accelerated? In that case, I misunderstood. I thought the wedge accelerated to the right.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder The block has an acceleration component to the left. The wedge has an acceleration component to the right. Both are accelerating.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Now you make it somewhat complicated. To which of the two a force is applied? To the block, or to the wedge?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder By Newton's third law, the block exerts a force on the wedge and the wedge exerts a force on the block. The gives the block an acceleration component to the left and the wedge an acceleration component to the right. Both the block and the wedge experience forces, hence their corresponding acceleration as per Newton's second law.

Comment: @BioPhysicist But on which of the two the force (I assume the force to be an em force) gets a grip? I know what you say in your comment, but that didn't answer the question. Is the wedge accelerated or the block (this makes a difference).

Comment: @BioPhysicist **the wedge accelerates in direction $\vec{a}$**, which means the wedge is accelerated to the right and the acceleration on the block becomes more vertical, i.e. the normal force is reduced. If the wedge accelerates beyond a certain limit, the block will just fall down.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I am not sure what you mean by "gets a grip". Both the wedge and the block are accelerated. Yes, the acceleration of the block becomes more vertical compared to a stationary wedge, but the block still has a leftward component due to the normal force that is still present. Perhaps you think there needs to be some force to keep the block "attached" to the wedge. This is not the case; no such force is present or needed here.

Comment: @BioPhysicist When the force on the wedge (directed to the right.) becomes bigger than a certain limit, the block will fall freely (the block will have no contact with the wedge anymore; the normal force has become zero), tracing out the trajectory of a parabole. By getting a grip I mean taking hold of, being applied to, exerted on, etc..