# Why is it necessary for the block to not move only when the wedge accelerates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Angel of inclination = $37^{\circ}$

Here , there a wedge of mass 5m and a constant force is being applied on the wedge . Now , it says in book that for the mass m (block) to not move , the wedge must accelerate. I don’t understand why must the block accelerate so that the block m does not move and why not let the wedge move with a certain constant velocity.

I know one reason is constant force but if it moves with a certain constant velocity at some point. Then ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does this block move backwards?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578063/157014)

Comment: I think one needs the angle of inclination to solve this.

Comment: @Gert take it as 37 degree. Done

Comment: No one is saying 'constant velocity'.

Comment: @Gert  what do you mean to convey sir

Comment: The block isn't moving means it doesn't accelerate, not that it moves with constant velocity.

Comment: No. My question was that if the wedge moves with s constant velocity rancher than accelerating. Would the mass fall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All velocity is relative. If an object is moving at a constant velocity, the numerical value and direction of that velocity can be *anything you choose* depending on your reference frame. You can choose to view the block and wedge as being at rest, moving at a constant 0 m/s. Or, you could hop in a car and drive away from the block and wedge and a constant 10 m/s, and view the block and wedge as moving away from you at 10 m/s. Whatever velocity you choose to assign to the block and wedge certainly cannot change its physical behavior - whether I choose to say that the block is a rest or moving at a constant 10 m/s depends entirely on my point of view, and changes nothing whatsoever about what the block and wedge are actually doing.

Basically, being at rest and moving at a constant velocity are *fundamentally the same*, since it depends entirely on your personal choice of how you view the problem. Anything that occurs at rest will also occur when moving at a constant velocity. It's quite intuitive that while at rest, the block will simply slide down the wedge, since there's nothing holding it in place. That will also occur in the exact same way if you drive away from the apparatus and view it as moving at a constant velocity. Since the block slides down the wedge while at rest, it also slides down the wedge while moving at a constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The block of mass $m$ is experiencing the force of gravity in downward direction (call it $y$ axis).
.
So we can break it in two components, one along the inclined surface of wedge and one perpendicular to the previous one.

So the component of gravity tangential to inclined to surface or wedge should be counter, or else there will be a external unbalanced force, that means it will move.

So, to make it at rest in $y$ axis, there should be force and that comes from our acceleration of wedge and we call there is a pseudo force on mass $m$ when observing in the wedge's reference frame.